# VBA Auto Sort when formula result changes

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a function where I calculate the averages of some scores, and then transfer the scores to a 'sheet' adjacent to it.

In this sheet, I transferred over the Adjacent Ratings calculated in Column C to Column H simply by giving the cells in Column H formulas, such as selecting H2 and giving it the formula of =C12 etc to correspond to the category.

I then used this code to sort Out the AVERAGE RATINGS sheet by ascending order.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Range("F2:H4").Sort Key1:=Range("H2"), _
Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
End Sub
```

However, when I do this, and the ratings under Column H get sorted, I find that the formulas of each average rating doesn't match to what I had originally input.

For example, I input the average rating formula for Ease of Finding Way Through Airport's as =C12 under column H.
However, when the ratings get sorted, I find that the average rating formula for Ease of Finding Way Through Airport automatically changes to something like =C13 or =C14 or =C12 instead. This in turn changes the value as well.

Whenever I edit the raw ratings to obtain a new average score, the average ratings in Column C somehow won't correspond to the scores in Column H as well.

[image: An image of the sheet]

Comment: You could use `INDEX` as your formula.

Comment: Maybe all you need to do is lock down the Row by adding `$` in front of the row index.  So instead of `=C12` use `=C$12`.